# How can I list EventIDs with Qualifiers using win32evtlog

Tags: python, windows, events, logging

When running a simple [win32evtlog](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) - I can list a large number of events - but when I filter to the ones I require; e.g. 6005, they fail to appear. I have filtered to ones that are visible and they can be found.

On the following code (Python 3.7 & win32 v222), if you take out the IF statement for 6005's, you get a run of Events. Change the IF statement to one of the numbers; e.g. 16, you should get some results.

```py
import win32evtlog as wlg

handle = wlg.OpenEventLog(None,'System')
flags = wlg.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|wlg.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ

while True:
    events = wlg.ReadEventLog(handle, flags, 0)
    for event in events:
        if event.EventID == 6005:
            print('Event ID:', event.EventID)
            print('Time Generated:', event.TimeGenerated)
```

I can return results using Powershell, and a manual check will find 6005's in Windows Event Viewer.

```bsh
Get-EventLog -LogName system | where-object {$_.eventid -eq 6005}
```

---

With some research while I was writing this question - I found that the Event API has a different method for certain events, as they include Qualifiers:

```xml
<EventID Qualifiers="32768">6005</EventID>
```

So it seems I need to find a way to convert Qualified Events (sometimes called InstanceID's) in a similar manner as this code does
[Scalyr](https://github.com/scalyr/scalyr-agent-2/blob/master/scalyr_agent/builtin_monitors/windows_event_log_monitor.py) [Line 375+]
I'm unable to decipher the code atm as I'm still learning - but I get the gist.

Comment: Eventually found that if I change  
`if event.EventID & 0xffff == 6005:`  
I'll get a result, but not displayed as 6005

Answer (score 2):

Eeeeeventually - I basically needed to add 1 bit to the result to receive the right answer.

```
import win32evtlog as wlg

handle = wlg.OpenEventLog(None,'System')
flags = wlg.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|wlg.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ

while True:
    events = wlg.ReadEventLog(handle, flags, 0)
    for event in events:
        if event.EventID & 0x1fff == 6005:
            print('Event ID:', event.EventID  & 0x1fff)
            print('Time Generated:', event.TimeGenerated)
```

And researching something else - came up with this answer from someone else on here who had a similar question  [Unusual event.EventID numbers like -2147481364 in Python using win32evtlog from Pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779987/unusual-event-eventid-numbers-like-2147481364-in-python-using-win32evtlog-from)
For some reason, this never came up in search results before now...  But, linking here as it's a similar look at things.